# How do you temporarily make a sprite disappear in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity, I've added a 2D sprite which has the skin of a booster for my character's rocket boots. I want to make the 2D sprite appear after pressing space and disappear after 1/4 of a second.

How would I turn on and off the visibility of the thruster sprite from C# code?

Comment: Just a quick idea: You might want to try doing a particle system instead of just blinking the sprite on and off. For example, you could fire off a bunch of particles when the player presses space, giving the impression of a "burst" of smoke or fire coming from the boots. Particles can look better sometimes, not always; it's totally up to you

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look into using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). The idea is that it's a method call which may contain delays or waiting periods before the method is "done". See the linked page for a detailed explanation.

Here is a sample coroutine method:

```
public IEnumerator ShowBoostersForQuarterSecond() {
    spriteRenderer.enabled = true;           //show
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);  //wait
    spriteRenderer.enabled = false;          //hide
}
```

And you would call it by doing

```
StartCoroutine(ShowBoostersForQuarterSecond());
```

Note that you might have to do `gameObject.renderer` instead of `spriteRenderer`. Or make a field to hold the Sprite Renderer reference, up to you.